# Extended Gerschgorin Circle Theorem (for irreducible A)

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Let $A$ be $n$ by $n$ and irreducible. Show that if an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ lies on the boundary of one Gershgorin disk, then it lies on the boundary of all Gershgorin disks.

I'm having trouble here--I figure I'll need to utilize the original Gershgorin theorem result, and also some relation between irreducibility and invertibility, but I really don't know where to begin. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is $A$ a non-negative matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not necessarily, it's just irreducible